# How to make a window fit the width of a screen in GTK+/GTKmm

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm

I have trouble making a window in GTKmm (C++, GTK+, GTKmm 3.22).

The window itself is empty (containing "Hello world").

What I want is that the window's height get set to the maximum height possible for a window, as if it is maximized, while the width is kept at an arbitrary value (200px).

I have huge trouble finding anything in this documentation https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/ or even the gtkmm doc from my linux distro.

Where can I find this kind of info?
And what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may do this by setting geometry hints:

> void Gtk::Window::set_geometry_hints  (   Widget&     geometry_widget,
>         const Gdk::Geometry&    geometry,       Gdk::WindowHints    geom_mask   )
>
> This function sets up hints about how a window can be resized by the
>   user.
>
> You can set a minimum and maximum size; allowed resize increments
>   (e.g. for xterm, you can only resize by the size of a character);
>   aspect ratios; and more. See the Gdk::Geometry struct.
>
> Parameters
>       geometry_widget   Widget the geometry hints used to be applied to or nullptr. Since 3.20 this argument is ignored and GTK behaves as if
>   nullptr was set.
>       geometry  Struct containing geometry information or nullptr.
>       geom_mask Mask indicating which struct fields should be paid attention to.

Cited from [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Window.html#a4564d6044ee0c89e02244559b6b5f916)

Comment: I still fail to see how I can do what I wanted. The geometry hints can set the size in pixels of the window, but not in percent of the area where windows are isn't it ? And there's no flag for a window called MAXIMIZE_ONLY_ON_HEIGHT or something like that isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Gtk::Widget::set_size_request()` to scale your window anyway you like.

```
Gdk::Display *gdkDisplay = Gdk::Display::get_default().get();
Gdk::Screen *gdkScreen = gdkDisplay->get_default_screen().get();
myWindow->set_size_request(200, gdkScreen->get_height() - 1);
```

Note that myWindow may be a Gtk::Window derived class, or an instance of Gtk::Window* .